I need help with asr_evaluation library
I have an assignment for which i need to find out the word error rate. Now asr_evaluation is supposed to be the library that i use but i am not able to use it.
Help.
Link: https://github.com/belambert/asr-evaluation?tab=readme-ov-file

Hi @Push29, welcome to the site. When you say "I am not able to use it", you are not giving enough information for us to understand the problem. Please, provide a detailed description of what the problem is.
